# Changing Sign in method in Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have a Flutter app for Android and IOS. Initially when I published the app I allowed users to sign in with **Google, Facebook, Apple and Email**.

Now I want to remove **Google, Facebook and Apple** sign in methods and only keep the sign up with **email & password**. My problem is, there are many users already signed up with Facebook and Google.

I wanted to know, is there any way to change all the non **email & password** users to change **email & password** sign in method & send them an email verification email?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       FirebaseUser use = await _auth.currentUser();
        use.linkWithCredential(credential).then((value) {
          print("done----------------------${value.user}");
        });
```

you can link your accounts

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Auth user accounts can't simply be converted as you describe.  What you can do is have each user go through an auth flow that has them [link an email/password auth method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) to their existing account, then unlink the original method.  There is no automation for this - it will require user input to go through the linking process.